# Asp.net mvc routing 404 - File or directory not found

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, routes

I define a route in RouteConfig for new url like this http://itface.ir/home/detail/439/Newtech,
"New tech" is subject and sometimes it has to be in another language like Persian , it works correctly on localhost but after deploying the below url I get the following error :

http://itface.ir/home/detail/439/سلام

Error 404 - File or directory not found.

I search for it but did not find any answer

Comment: can you write your route code here?

Comment: `routes.MapRoute(name: "Test", url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{subject}", defaults: new { controller = "home", action = "detail",  id = UrlParameter.Optional,subject=UrlParameter.Optional });`

Comment: what is setting of your IIS application pool? I mean does it pointing to correct framework ?

Comment: No, I checking it , I used .netframework  4.5 but Framework Version on the server is 4.0

Comment: Also do you have hosted it as website directly in IIS or is it a subfolder. If it is a subfolder then it will not work

Comment: it is in /httpdocs/"here", Why?

Comment: that's is problem its considering it as subfolder.

Comment: What is the solution?

Comment: Add a subfolder in your route then it will work fine.